# Regularity vs smoothness in positive characteristic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, positive-characteristic, regular-rings

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_local_ring#Origin_of_basic_notions) that a scheme over a perfect field is smooth at $x$ if and only if it is regular at $x$, and that these two properties are not equivalent over non-perfect fields. What is an example of a finite-type scheme over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ with a regular, singular point? And is there a simple additional condition that can can be added to regularity to ensure smoothness?

Comment: $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p(T^{\frac{1}{p}})\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p(T))$, and geometric regularity (i.e. regularity also after base change to the algebraic, or even perfect, closure).

Comment: Is this the only kind of regularity without smoothness, or is it a thornier issue? For instance, given regular finite type $X$ over non-perfect $k$ is there some sort of factoring $X \to X' \to \mathrm{Spec}(k)$ where $X'$ is smooth and $X \to X'$ has a condition like locally purely inseparable?